# First-In and Last-Out times for Night Shift and Day Shift Employees

Tags: sql-server, c#

Kindly share suitable technique to handle night shift as well as day shift.
Below are the shifts,

```
Night,  2020-07-20 17:00 to 2020-07-21 02:00
Night,  2020-07-20 17:00 to 2020-07-21 02:00
Day,    2020-07-20 08:00 to 2020-07-20 17:00
Day,    2020-07-20 08:30 to 2020-07-20 17:30
```

In Database there are only two fields

```
1: SSN (which is employee Code)
2: CheckTime e.x. (2020-07-20 16:48:30.000)
```

in Day shift i can get first in last out from Min entry and Max entry.
but in night shift I can't get any accurate data because of the date change.

Comment: When you say handle you mean to find out who is the first employee to start working and the last employee to stop working at the same day or to find out the time one employee starts and the time that same employee ends his shift?

Comment: I need to manage time of one employee that starts and end shift  in my application.

Comment: To achieve that you could use the function dateadd using the hour option like this: `SELECT DATEADD(HOUR, 20, GETDATE()),GETDATE();`. If you have any problems using it, tell me and I can try to help you writing the query.

Comment: Generally speaking, there's no reliable algorithm that can fully infer shift lengths from a mere list of checkpoint times or even in/out times. Human inference has some success, but that's based on a dynamic knowledge of normal work patterns and unusual business events, plus an ability to identify and react sensibly to anomalies, plus the ability to seek further information in the hardest of cases.

Answer (score 0):

Could you write a query to use BETWEEN the shift start date time and the shift end date time (both held in variables) that returns all the SSN and check times in that period? If you insert the results of that into a temporary table, you could then have another query on that temporary table for your MIN and MAX values. Doing it like that means you don't need to worry about a change of date because your only concerned with the data in your temporary table. Also, using variables would let you reuse the script for different date and times for shifts.

Comment: Can you please write the query even a dummy data query. how would i manage enteries in temporary table to take min and max values in specific date when user's time in is before shift time in and user time out is after shift time out.